# Find the least $m$ such that $0.\overline{2}_b<\log_{b}{2}$

Tags: number-theory

> Find the least $m$ such that $0.\overline{2}_b<\log_{b}{2}$ for all $b>m$.

I didn't see a nice analytic way of solving this, so I was wondering if there was an easier way of solving it.

Comment: $-0.\overline{2}_b=-\dfrac2{b-1}$

Comment: Is there a negative sign on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The result holds for $b \geq 7$.

$$0.\bar2_b = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{b^n} = \frac{2}{b-1}$$

So the inequality is the same as

$$2 < \log_b 2^{b-1}$$

$$b^2 < 2^{b-1}$$

This holds when $b=7$. Each time we increment $b$, the RHS doubles in size but the LHS grows less than that. Hence it holds when $b \geq 7$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean negative.

Comment: I changed it again.

Comment: How would you prove this: Let $b>2$ and $1 \leq k \leq m$ where $a,b,k,m$ are integers. Prove that $$0.\overline{2}_b+\sum_{i=1}^k \log_{b}\left(1-b^{-(m-i+1)}\right)<\log_{b}{2}.$$